# How do I receive server responses in Windows Universal Apps?

Tags: c#, sockets, stream, client, win-universal-app

I am following the Windows Universal Example about StreamSockets. It tells me how to connect to a server and write to the server as a client, but it doesn't tell me how to read the response from the server. The example is https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/StreamSocket

In Console Applications I can use a StreamReader and StreamWriter to read and write to a socket stream. It looks like the comparable in Universal Apps is DataReader/DataWriter. But no data is showing up in my DataReader buffer. Specifically reader.UnconsumedBufferLength returns 0. Another problem with my code is I am clicking a button to print the response buffer. I would like my program to print the response buffer automatically when it receives data. I assume I need to make an event listener, but this is not in the sample either. Here is my print buffer method which is called after I connect (when I use my connect method to a remote FTP server, I get no exceptions. I assume it is connected also because the Socket is not null).:

```
 private async void PrintBuffer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StreamSocket socket;
        object outValue;
        //If we havent initialized socket, dont use the socket
        if (!CoreApplication.Properties.TryGetValue("clientSocket", out outValue))
        {
            Response.Text = "Please connect before sending.";
            return;
        }

        socket = (StreamSocket)outValue;

        // Create a DataReader if we did not create one yet. Otherwise use one that is already cached.
        DataReader reader;
        if (!CoreApplication.Properties.TryGetValue("clientDataReader", out outValue))
        {
            reader = new DataReader(socket.InputStream);
            CoreApplication.Properties.Add("clientDataReader", reader);
        }
        else
        {
            reader= (DataReader)outValue;
        }

        // Read the locally buffered data to the network.
        try
        {
            uint unread = reader.UnconsumedBufferLength;
            await reader.LoadAsync(unread);
            Response.Text = "\"" + reader.ReadString(unread) + "\" read successfully.";
        }  
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // If this is an unknown status it means that the error if fatal and retry will likely fail.
            if (SocketError.GetStatus(exception.HResult) == SocketErrorStatus.Unknown)
            {
                throw;
            }

            Response.Text = "Send failed with error: " + exception.Message;
        }
    }
```

UPDATE: I have found another example here: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/SocketActivityStreamSocket/cs/SocketActivityStreamSocket/Scenario1_Connect.xaml.cs and Microsoft randomly tries 250 in their LoadAsync function... Is this the only option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 250 is arbitrary, but there is a setting on the reader that will stop after it receives one or more bytes.

```
            reader.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;
            await reader.LoadAsync(250);
            Response.Text = "\"" + reader.ReadString(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength) + "\" read successfully.";
```